# Run a foreach loop on returned results in a stored procedure.

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that returns a result from table1, I then use that result in another stored procedure to update table2. I was wondering if I could combine this into one stored procedure, the problem is that it would need to run a foreach loop on table2 based on the value from table1 to find all the values to update. No idea where to start or if its even possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is example of running something for each item. But for update you should not need this, you should be able to solve this with CROSS JOIN, anyway example below.

```
 declare @i int;
set @i = 0;
declare @t table
(
int id identity,
varchar(max) col1,
varchar(max) col2
)

insert into @t(col1,col2)
select col1,
        col2 from  FROM        [Table]


set i = 0;
declare @sum int
set @sum = 0;
while(i < select count(*) from @t)
begin 
 select case when (col1 == col2) then @sum = @sum+1 else @sum from @t
where id = i;
i++;
end
```